# Network configuration for Security Onion on VMWare ESX

Tags: ids, vmware

I'm setting up an IDS using Security Onion on VMWare ESX. I have a VLAN from the (physical) switch which has the network SPAN port; this is feeding into the ESX virtual switch, and this port group is set to Promiscuous. Likewise, the second network interface on the VM is connected to this ESX portgroup and is also set to promiscuous (auto-configuration by Security Onion).

My problem is that no traffic is coming to Snort in any way that I can detect. SGUIL and ELSA have no logs; even a tcpdump on that port is showing nothing. I know there is traffic on the network, but I don't know where it is being lost.

Has anyone set up something similar? Was there any particular configuration needed?

Comment: The problem is likely in your Vswitch config.  Can you post it?

Comment: I've got the distributed switch config from the VMWare team: http://imgur.com/a/BLoyQ

Comment: It looks increasingly likely that the feed from the initial SPAN on the physical switch is misconfigured. I'll update this once it's confirmed.